# Finite index Fuchsian subgroup

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

Suppose I have a polygon $F$ and a group $G$ of isometries of the upper half plane, $\mathbb{H}^2$, such that $F$ tessellate $\mathbb{H}^2$ under the action of $G$. Can we always say that $G$ has a finite index discrete subgroup which acts freely on the upper half plane?

This is true if $G$ is a triangle group. But I am not sure if it is true in general.

Comment: Yes. This is usually known as Selberg's Lemma. Maybe a nice reference is https://www.jstor.org/stable/2373096?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents where it is stated as Lemma 2.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the reference.